# pannellum cordova file could not be accessed in ios application

Tags: ios, cordova, cross-domain

I am new to ios application development.

Presently I'm developing hybrid application. In my project I'm using **pannellum.js** as a framework for panorama image view. Everything works fine when tested in Android.

When I try deploying the same code in iOS I'm getting problem when loading image in Pannellum framework. I don't know where i missed anything. Getting the below error when trying to deploy iOS app.

**file:///*/pan_images/entry_gate.jpg could not be accessed**.

i don't know how to solve it.any help appreciated.